# How to execute nLog?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

I am having a data written using nLog

Code snippet:

```
        <target xsi:type="File"
            name="AAAAA"
            filename="${basedir}\..\AAAAA\AAAAA${shortdate}.csv">
        <layout xsi:type="CsvLayout" delimeter="Semicolon" withHeader="True" quoting="Auto">
            <column name="Date" layout="${longdate}" />
            <column name="Thread" layout="${threadid} (${threadname})" />
            <column name="Level" layout="${level}" />
            <column name="Logger" layout="${logger:shortName=False}" />
            <column name="NDC" layout="${ndlc:separator=, }" />
            <column name="Message" layout="${message}" />
        </layout>
    </target>
```

How do I execute that logger? And where is the best place to do that?

Comment: By execution you mean to completely finish him or are we looking into interrogations here?

Comment: I mean how to execute that for instance when you are executing a method or something

Comment: where is your logging code? This only shows a small part of the configuration.. You need to use an ILogger, inject it or create it, then use that to _logger.Log()

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial

Answer (score 1):

To make NLog log into your file, on top of your target, you just need a logging rule in the config that refers that target:

```
...</target></targets>
<rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="File" />
</rules>
```

after you add that your code should just trigger this file to be created just by logging - so nothing special required in code

```
   ILogger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
   _logger.Info("Work started");
```

If that does not work it might be that your configuration is invalid and by default NLog will not throw exceptions and silently fail to log. You can change that behaviour by adding attributes to nlog configuration node:

```
<nlog throwConfigExceptions="true" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.txt"
```

with that you will be able to see why your logger is not working.